# How to join a string by line endings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings, which I wish to join by line ending:

```
a = ['first line', 'second line', 'third line']
```

I want to join them in ruby in the most idiomatic way, using the OS default line ending, so that it would use `'\r\n'` to join the lines on windows and it would use `'\n'` to join the lines on *NIX. In python, I would do this:

```
os.linesep.join(a)
```

How would I do this idiomatically in ruby?

Comment: Do you wish for the last line to also have a line ending?  Strictly speaking, joining does not terminate the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the array of strings with a newline:

```
puts a.join("\n")
```

Example of my terminal output:

```
1.9.3-p484 :008 > puts a.join("\n")
first line
second line
third line
```

However, in reference OP's question, to join the array of strings with a line ending just do this:

```
puts a.join($/)
```

Example of my terminal output:

```
1.9.3-p484 :008 > puts a.join($/)
first line
second line
third line
```

Comment: But what about windows? Wouldn't that code do the wrong thing in windows? You have not addressed whether or not this will work on all platforms and why.

Comment: @djhaskin987 I am using mac, so I cannot truly replicate your scenario. Just trying to help :)

Comment: I think I found the answer. Use `$/` instead of `"\n"` and substitute word "newline" for "line ending" and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @djhaskin987 Done! Thanks for coming back and and reporting your findings!

Answer (score 4):

> In python, I would do this:
>
> ```
> os.linesep.join(a)
> ```

Not generally--only in special circumstances.  You have not given any indication that you actually require something like `os.linesep`.  If you use that idiom generally, then on windows you will generally end up with `"\r\r\n"` in your output.

> I want to join them in ruby in the most idiomatic way, using the OS
>   default line ending, so that it would use '\r\n' to join the lines on
>   windows and it would use '\n' to join the lines on *NIX.

First of all, `'\n'` and `'\r\n'` are not what you think they are.  Unlike with python, in ruby single quoted strings are different than double quoted strings.

Secondly, it depends on what you plan to do with the string, but generally you would write:

```
array.join("\n")
```

...just like you *should* be doing in python.

Also, note that the ruby global variable `$/` is the *input* record separator, used by gets(), etc., to determine when to stop reading in data, and therefore using the *input record separator* with `join()` is non-sensical.  Also, on Windows I believe the output of:

```
p ['A', 'B', 'C'].join $/
```

will be:

```
"A\r\r\nB\r\r\nC"
```

Anyone with a Windows machine want to confirm that?